# RxJava network requests and caching

Tags: android, rx-java

I am seeking an example of a flow I'm trying to implement with help of RxJava.

Suppose I want to show a list of data. The flow should look something like this:

1. Read cache. If it contains the data, show it;
2. Send an API request to the server:

   If it returned the data, then cache it and show it.

   If it returned and error and there was no cached data, then show an error.

   If it returned and error and there was something cached, then do nothing.

Right now I have a [method that does something similar](https://gist.github.com/egor-n/581c54db79bd1c1defed) (with lots of inspiration from [Jake's u2020](https://github.com/cgruber/u2020/blob/dagger2/src/main/java/com/jakewharton/u2020/data/GalleryDatabase.java#L35)). The main difference is that it uses in-memory caching, which means there's no need for a separate `Observable` for reading from cache and it can be done synchronously.

I don't know how to combine two observables (one for reading from cache and the other for API call) and obtain the flow described above.

Any suggestions?

Comment: Looks you need `amb`: https://github.com/ReactiveX/RxJava/wiki/Conditional-and-Boolean-Operators#amb

Comment: @zsxwing could you provide an example? I am open to suggestions, even though I found an answer (which is not perfect).

Comment: I would tend to leave the cache handling to the network client. If you use HTTP, there are header in the response that are dedicated to indicate the client what type of cache should be implemented, how long should object be kept... Not to mention that there is also the possibility to verify that your cache is still valid and update it if necessary (return code 304).

Comment: @EgorN I think you want the result from the first returned Observable, either from the cache or the server. If so, you can use `amb(readDataFromCache(), apiCall())`.

Comment: @zsxwing that's not really what I want. I want it to show cached data first and then if server's response is OK, then show the updated data from the server.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is my solution:

```
readDataFromCache().defaultIfEmpty(null)
        .flatMap(new Func1<Data, Observable<Data>>() {

            @Override
            public Observable<Data> call(final Data data) {
                if (data == null) {
                    // no cache, show the data from network or throw an error
                    return apiCall();
                } else {
                    return Observable.concat(
                            Observable.just(data),
                            // something cached, show the data from network or do nothing.
                            apiCall().onErrorResumeNext(Observable.<Data>empty()));
                }
            }
        });
```

I don't add the `subscribeOn` and `observeOn` because I'm not sure `readDataFromCache()` should use `ioScheduler` or `uiScheduler`.

Comment: The only problem I've had with this is when `readDataFromCache()` returns an error. `onErrorResumeNext(Observable.<Data>empty())` should be added before `defaultIfEmpty(null)` to swallow the error.

Answer (score 3):

I think I solved my problem. The observable chain looks like so:

```
apiCall()
        .map(data -> dataInMemory = data)
        .onErrorResumeNext(t -> data == null ?
                Observable.just(Data.empty()) : Observable.empty())
        .startWith(readDataFromCache().map(data -> dataInMemory = data))
        .subscribeOn(ioScheduler)
        .observeOn(uiScheduler)
        .subscribe(dataRequest);
```

The main point is, that if `readDataFromCache()` throws an error, it will call `onCompleted()` without calling `onError()`. So it should be a custom `Observable` which you can control.

`Data.empty()` is a stub for my data - the `Subscriber` should treat it as an error.

`dataInMemory` is a member in my controller which acts as in-memory cache.

---

**EDIT:** the solution doesn't work properly. The completion of one use case (see comment) is not achieved.

**EDIT 2:** well, the solution **does** work properly after some tweaking. The fix was returning different types of observables depending on the state of in-memory cache. Kind of dirty.

Comment: Well, my solution doesn't work. If `readDataFromCache()` goes well and shows some data and the `apiCall()` returns an error, it shows the error.